# Typescript array filtering not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a json object with array of data.i want to filter it with another array.

MY .ts file is as follows.

```
 let filter_bank_id=[4,25,6,1];
      console.log(filter_bank_id.length);

         if(data.offers){
            let last =data.offers.filter(offer=>{
              for(let i=0;i<filter_bank_id.length;i++){
                  if(data.offers[i]){
                    let bank=filter_bank_id[i];
                      if(bank){
                        if(bank===data.offers[i].bank_id){
                          return offer;
                        }
                      }
                  }else{
                  alert("nodata");
                  }
              }
            });  
          console.log(last);
         }
```

Here offers is the json object with multiple data.i want to filter it with filter_bank_id array.That means i want only offers with bank_id 4,25,6,1 as in the filter_bank_id array.But it is not working.
problem is with  " let last =data.offers.filter(offer=>" this line.when i give debugger it is not entering into it.My offers json object is below.

```
offers= [
    {
      "image": "assets\/banks\/axi1419231043.jpg",
      "offerid": 1,
      "id": "1",
      "bank_id": "1",
      "name": "AXIS BANK",
      "bank_interest": "10.99",
      "emi": "2,174",
      "processing_fee": "990",
      "precloser_cost": "0 %",
      "part_pay": "Yes",
      "insurance": null,
      "conditions": "",
      "intrest_1_year": 0,
      "intrest_total": 0
    },
    {
      "image": "assets\/banks\/hdfc1418896652.png",
      "offerid": 7,
      "id": "4",
      "bank_id": "4",
      "name": "HDFC BANK",
      "bank_interest": "10.99",
      "emi": "2,174",
      "processing_fee": "500",
      "precloser_cost": "4.49 % for 12-24 months,3.37 % for 24-36 months,2.25 % for 36-60 months,",
      "part_pay": "Yes",
      "insurance": "1,362",
      "conditions": "",
      "intrest_1_year": 0,
      "intrest_total": 0
    },
    {
      "image": "assets\/banks\/scb1438520764.png",
      "offerid": 2,
      "id": "16",
      "bank_id": "16",
      "name": "SCB",
      "bank_interest": "11.00",
      "emi": "2,175",
      "processing_fee": "1000",
      "precloser_cost": "0 %",
      "part_pay": "Yes",
      "insurance": null,
      "conditions": "",
      "intrest_1_year": 0,
      "intrest_total": 0
    },
    {
      "image": "assets\/banks\/citi1419219218.png",
      "offerid": 3,
      "id": "2",
      "bank_id": "2",
      "name": "CITI BANK",
      "bank_interest": "11.49",
      "emi": "2,199",
      "processing_fee": "2999",
      "precloser_cost": "2 %",
      "part_pay": "Yes",
      "insurance": null,
      "conditions": "",
      "intrest_1_year": 0,
      "intrest_total": 0
    },
```

];

What is the problem with my filter.please help me.Thank in advance.

Comment: can you put your code on plunkr or jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Use filter like this

`offers.filter((offer) => filter_bank_ids.indexOf(offer.bank_id) > -1)`

Also check your types before using this snippet. I hope this will help you

Comment: it is also not working.The problem is with that filter.Dont know how to resolve?